# Does Azure ML have a way of specifying dropout?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, azure-machine-learning-service

The Net# neural network [specification language](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-azure-ml-netsharp-reference-guide/) for Azure does not seem to have an option for specifying [dropout](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14a/srivastava14a.pdf). Is this available or planned? Are there alternatives or equivalent (though perhaps differently named) options I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is available. Please submit your features request to user voice - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/257792-machine-learning